# Do Indians need a separate Hong Kong visa if we already have a Chinese visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, china, hong-kong

I have got a single-entry Chinese visa from India and now I planned to add Hong Kong to my trip plan.

Do I need a separate visa for Hong Kong, or can I use my Chinese visa instead? If I need a separate visa, is visa on arrival possible for Indians, or should I need to pre-apply?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your Chinese visa is not valid for Hong Kong (HK) as HK is a Special Administrative Region (SAR) and this has different rules than mainland China.

As an Indian national, you are allowed 14 days visa-free entry in HK, but you must complete a Pre-arrival Registration (PAR)

More info can be found on [HK Visa Information](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html#notes).

Answer (score 14):

Beyond the visa for HK as described in the other answer, you need to be aware that going to Hong Kong is considered like leaving China for visa purposes.

If you have a single-entry visa for China, you can visit China then HK, or HK then China, but if you intend to visit China, go to Hong Kong, and then back to China, then this won’t be possible with a single entry visa, you need a visa with at least two entries.